# Is Optional Traffic Possible For Cassandra Inter-node Encryption?

Tags: ssl, cassandra

We can implement client-node encryption for C* with optional traffic (encrypted and unencrypted connections are handled).

```
client_encryption_options:
enabled: false
# If enabled and optional is set to true encrypted and unencrypted connections are handled.
optional: false
keystore: conf/.keystore
keystore_password: cassandra
```

We don't have the same parameter available for inter-node communication.

Is there a way we can tweak the apache source code for custom implementation of C* with ***optional*** traffic for inter-node encryption?

Also can we implement inter-node encryption for C* without having a downtime?

Any links to apache source code for inter-node encryption would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please describe why you need this - what do you want to achieve...

Comment: Want to implement inter-node encryption on C* cluster in production without downtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to implement inter-node encryption without downtime by utilizing different ports for non-encrypted and encrypted traffic.

Take a look at `ssl_storage_port` and `storage_port` in the `cassandra.yaml` file. One can utilize the different storage ports to effectively support optional encryption by supporting both ports for a short time.

Note: In 4.0 Cassandra there is an optional flag on inter-node encryption and the `ssl_storage_port` is deprecated.